# Printing a staggered array if one of the results is equal to janurary

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay so I have a staggered array which stores months and temperatures ect.
What I need is for the array to print out but only if it matches what the user inputs. For example if the user inputs January I need it to display every value on the same row as every January

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string[] innerArray = data[i];
                            for (int a = 0; a < innerArray.Length; a++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(innerArray[a] + " ");
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
```

As of now it displays everything from the array but how can I filter it to only display results under January
attached an example of the console output[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns9J7.png)

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you find the january, the first array contains the months?

Comment: Sorry yes, I read them from a text file and the first array is months, 2nd is years 3rd is temperature. Want to display month, year and temperature where month =  January

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume each innerArray is the same length, so you should reverse inner and outer array in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data[0].Length; i++)
{
    if (data[0][i] == "January")
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < data.Length; a++)
        {
            if (a != 0)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.Write(data[a][i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

If possible, I would modify the datasource to rather have the first level of array to be your sample points, and the second level to contain your data (swap rows and columns if your initial source is a .csv file)

Answer (score 0):

If the first array contains the months you first have determine the index of the month, for example with [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx), then you can use `String.Join` and LINQ to select from others:

```
string[][] data = ...; // your jagged array
string month = "January"; // user input
string result = null;
string[] months = data[0];

int monthIndex = Array.FindIndex(months, m => m.Equals(month, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

if (monthIndex >= 0)
    result = string.Join(" ", data.Select(arr => arr[monthIndex]));
```